# How to read a csv file

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm trying to get the value in my csv which contains IP Addresses in the first column, and hostname in the second.

I tried to read the full csv, but I really have no idea how to select the first column.

The best will be to copy the first column in a board `$TheIPs = @()`
and same for the hostname.

```
$Currentpath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition 
$CheminCSV = $currentpath + '\LesIP.csv'

$file = Import-CSV $CheminCSV

$keys = Import-Csv .\keys.csv | select -ExpandProperty

Write-Host($file) #Show me all my csv
Write-Host($keys) # Not working
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include a small sample of the date, feel free to anonymise it with dummy data that is in the same format.

Comment: Paired arrays that match values by index (such as an IP array matched with a hostname array based on index) are a programming anti-pattern... something to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a CSV-File like this ...

```
IP,Hostname
123,host123
456,host456
789,host789
```

... you can access every column by its name like so ...

```
$csv = Import-Csv ".\LesIP.csv"

# Accessing the row "IP"
$csv."IP"
```

Please keep in mind that `Import-Csv` assumes you have a **Comma**-Delimited file with **UTF-8**-Encoding. If that's not the case, you can specify those properties by using the parameters `-Encoding` and `-Delimiter`

Answer (score 1):

You can find out about any object by using `Get-Member` like: `$keys | Get-Member` or `$keys | gm` for short.

The first line should contain headers.

So `$keys | select ip` for all the ip(s) assuming `ip` is the header.

Comment: Hi David, I would recommend take a look at the formatting options when submitting an answer. Formatting your code correctly and using line spacings will make your answer much easier to read :)

Answer (score 0):

Select the `IP` property values and then simply assign it a variable.

Using `ExpandProperty` will only include the IPs themselves and not include column header.

```
$Currentpath = split-path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition 
$CheminCSV = $currentpath + '\LesIP.csv'

$csv = Import-CSV $CheminCSV

$MyIPS = $csv | select -ExpandProperty IP

# and for hostnames
$MyHostnames = $csv | select -ExpandProperty HostName
```